# How to display html table initially shifted to hide the first column and then shown during horizontal scroll?

Tags: html-table

I want to create an html table inside a div tag. The div is 350px in width but the table inside is much wider, let's say 5 columns so a horizontal scroll will appear. My goal is to display initially the second to last column meaning the first column is shifted to the left and not visible at the first visit. If we scroll horizontally then the first column should be visible. CSS should be in a separate file meaning no inline css or assigning class for the table, tr td, th. We can only add a class to the div tag.

Thanks in advance.

Inside a div tag html table shift using css and class only.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a combination of CSS and JavaScript. Here are the css style

```
.table-container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.table-container table {
  margin-left: -100px; /* Adjust this value based on the width of your first column */
}
```

you can use JavaScript to detect when the table has been scrolled and adjust the margin-left of the table accordingly.

```
const tableContainer = document.querySelector('.table-container');
const table = tableContainer.querySelector('table');

tableContainer.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  const scrollLeft = tableContainer.scrollLeft;
  table.style.marginLeft = `-${scrollLeft}px`;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, It did shift the table to the left. For some reason, the horizontal bar is not visible nor the table is scrollable. Maybe we need to modify the code a little bit.